# SQL - Query Performance

Tags: mysql, query-performance

How to find the inefficient queries in mysql database  ? I want to do performance tuning on my queries , but i coudn't find where my queries are located ? Please suggest me where can i find mysql queries for my tables .

Thanks

Prabhakaran.R

Comment: they are in mysql stored procedures/functions/events/triggers, or most likely passed thru from your source code. programming language. php. what are you using ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query - Performance Optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477430/sql-query-performance-optimization)

Comment: post any particularly slow ones with schema, we can give it a go :>

Comment: @DrewPierce to find which one runs slow .. i need to get into logs , 
enable the slow query logs : set global slow _query_log ='ON' ,set global long_query_time = 1 ; but i cant get through /var/lib/mysql to see my logs .. it says permission denied . what to do ??

Comment: talk to the guy who can `sudo` ?

Comment: command pls ? is it sudo cd mysql or sudo mysql ?

Comment: @Drew Pierce Thanks , it worked .

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the [general log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and [slow query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) logs.

Enabling general query log will log all the queries and might be heavy if you have many reads/writes. In slow query log, you can mention a threshold and only queries taking time beyond some time will be logged. Post that, you can manually analyze it or you can use tools provided( Percona has great tools)

Comment: enable the slow query logs : set global slow _query_log ='ON' ,set global long_query_time = 1 ; but i cant get through /var/lib/mysql to see my logs .. it says permission denied . what to do ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you analyzed your queries with [explain plans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)? You may be able to find a query that will return the result set you wish that isn't as heavy a load on the query engine. Remember to only select the columns you actually need (try to avoid SELECT *), well planned indexing and to use inner/outer joins in favour of a huge list of WHERE clause filters.

Good luck.

RP

Comment: i want to know - how can i find my slow processing queries ? where it is located ?

Comment: enable the slow query logs : set global slow _query_log ='ON' ,set global long_query_time = 1 ; but i cant get through /var/lib/mysql to see my logs .. it says permission denied . what to do ??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others said, use `pt-query-digest` (from percona.com) to summarize the slowlog.  That will tell you the worst queries.

Performance tuning often involves knowing what indexes to put on tables.  [*My index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) is one place to learn how to build an `INDEX` for a given `SELECT`.